# complex sentence ending in a noun breakdown

Tags: translation, kanji

> どうせ知識だけ頭に詰め込んでる兵器

A couple things confuse me:  How can we end a sentence in a noun?  Whats the 「込んでる」?  I thought something deru, but it doesn't use 出る.

Comment: The original is 「どうせ知識だけ頭に詰め込んでる兵器オタクなんでしょ？」, no?

Comment: @ちょこれーと Yes it is.  In my confusion I cutoff a part.

Comment: Okay, so 知識だけ頭に詰め込んでる modifies 兵器オタク.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's read as

> Douse chishiki dake atama ni tsume konderu heiki (otaku) 
>   どうせちしきだけあたまにつめこんでるへいき(おたく)

How can we end a sentence in a noun? 
-- I think it's because this is not a sentence but a relative noun clause.

Whats the 「込んでる」? 
-- It's [詰]{つ}め[込]{こ}んで(い)る, [詰め込む](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%A9%B0%E3%82%81%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80) + いる.

cf. [知識を詰め込む in Weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%9F%A5%E8%AD%98%E3%82%92%E8%A9%B0%E3%82%81%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80)